# Making a Linq property optional while using in Webservice

Tags: asp.net, linq, web-services

I am using LINQ object in my webservice and consumed by iphone and android developers.
Now i have added some new fields in a table which in turn will be used linq object.

I want to know some way by which i can mark some linq properties as optional i.e. if iphone and android deve. doesnt pass that properties then no error will show up.

Thanks
Gaurav

Comment: Do you mean LINQ to SQL?

Comment: What do you mean LINQ object in webservice? Please clarify and put some code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not recommended to embed your LINQ objects directly in a web service.  Create data objects specifically for the web service that captures the relevant parameters for each web service call.  This will protect your service consumers from changes to the underlying data storage and allow you to more tightly control what is known to the consumers.  You can then use the adapter pattern to convert objects in your web service to LINQ objects for submitting to database.

Secondly, regarding your question about optional parameters.  With custom data objects, this will be easily done with nullable properties (for primitive types), or just `null` for object types.  If you must use the LINQ objects, making the fields nullable in the database will also cause the properties to be nullable, and thus optional to service consumers.